# Why is there no such word as "percentagely"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, percentages

If I want to use an adverb to say, for example:

> I'm not sure you could do it. I can say that `percentagely / in percentage` there are few hopes.

Is there a specific reason there is no such word in contemporary English?

Comment: Do you mean [percentagewise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=percentagely%2C+percentagewise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpercentagely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpercentagewise%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, something that can be described in percentage. By the graph that you posted seems that the word "percentagely" is relatively recent, used for a while and then dead. Yet it seems pretty natural for me to say "percentagely"

Comment: I think you're looking for "***statistically***".

Comment: The reason it doesn't exist is because not enough people have felt a need to create it;  apparently the other words given (*percentagewise*, *statistically*) do the job well enough that creating yet another word has not been necessary.

Comment: @FdT No one can possibly answer for certain why that formation never caught on, but my money's on the fact that a soft G (IPA dʒ) followed by L is relatively awkward to vocalize for most native English speakers. I'm hard-pressed to think of other examples of that in the English lexicon.

Comment: @nollidge largely, hugely, strangely, savagely... I think you're right in saying that the combination is probably a factor, though. It's an unusual sound pairing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such word because there is that linguistic phenomenon called ["blocking"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(linguistics)).

We already have *percentagewise*, so its existence blocks *percentagely* from getting any traction, or indeed from being created in the first place.

This is actually the same mechanism that ensures we still have *children* and not *childs*, or say *unequal* but *inequality*.

*Percentagely, childs, unequality* are only likely to get any traction at all in a meaning (register, dialect...) different from that of *percentagewise, children, inequality*.

Basically whenever there are two (or more) different morphological paths we can take, each of them leads to a different meaning. If we have but one meaning to cover, then whatever path we've taken, it won't let us go back and pick one of the others to arrive at just the same destination. This is a basic linguistic mechanism, not limited to English.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing that is actually quite important in this particular case: the suffix *-ly* is only really used to form adverbs from *adjectives*. When applied to a *noun*, it quite typically gets you not an adverb but an adjective. There are a few exceptions as with everything, but still, one could argue the particular alternative path you're looking to take simply does not exist — or rather, it leads not just to a different *meaning* but to a different *part of speech*.

Comment: I suggest folding that comment into your answer.  It's a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "[percentually](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/percentually)". It may be less frequently used, but it does exist and its more difficult (= more Latin) formation is what prevents it from being widely utilized (or known).